# ClassCastException: SoapPrimitive can't be cast to SoapObject (Apparently there is no SoapPrimitive here)

Tags: android, json, serialization, ksoap2, classcastexception

I am consuming a `SOAP based web-service` using `ksoap2`, and receiving a `JSON response` from the webservice, which I am storing in a `SoapObject`.

The next step is to *parse the `JSON`*. For that I am trying to get each `property` from the response SoapObject and store it in another `SoapObject`, for further processing (like getting the `name` and `value` etc.)

```
SoapObject soapObjectEach= (SoapObject) postResult.getProperty(i);
```

But I am getting an **exception** at this statement: **java.lang.ClassCastException: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive cannot be cast to org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject**

**postResult is a SoapOject.** This suggests me that postResult.getProperty() probably returns a SoapPrimitive? But I am almost certain that it is not the case, as the [documentation](http://kobjects.org/ksoap2/doc/api/org/ksoap2/serialization/SoapObject.html#getProperty%28int%29) says, "Returns the desired property"

***So can anybody suggest something about it?*** I have seen other questions about this ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18892434/java-lang-classcastexception-org-ksoap2-serialization-soapprimitive-cannot-be-c), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220502/org-ksoap2-serialization-soapobject-cannot-be-cast-to-org-ksoap2-serialization-s)) but did not get to a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets diagonize your code:

```
SoapObject soapObjectEach= (SoapObject) postResult.getProperty(i);
```

As you said postResult is a soapobject. And from the documentation on getproperty says:

```
getProperty

public java.lang.Object getProperty(int index)
Returns a specific property at a certain index.
Specified by:
getProperty in interface KvmSerializable
Parameters:
index - the index of the desired property
Returns:
the desired property
```

The getproperty returns the property at the index and not something that can be always be  cast into a soapobject. And from your exception we can see it is returning an object of type soapprimitive. So the solution would be something similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799775/ksoap2-android-cast-class-exception-soapobject).

Comment: Thank you very much. That solved the problem. But that answer does not state why or how. So can you tell me if you know that?

Comment: its simple soapprimitive cannot be cast into soapobject http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840322/how-does-the-java-cast-operator-work this link explains what you need